# Repeater DataBind error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Half a day spent on this one...

On a page, I have two repeaters like so:

```
<% if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"])) { %>

    <asp:Repeater ID="auth_items" runat="server">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="/admin/auth.aspx?action=view&amp;id=<%# Eval("id") %>"><%# Security.script(Eval("name").ToString()) %></a><br />
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>

<% } else { %>    

    <asp:Repeater ID="auth_item" runat="server">

        <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Security.script(Eval("name").ToString()) %>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>    

<% } %>
```

and in code behind:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY attr1 DESC";
else
{
    id = Security.sql(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    sql = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE attr2=" + id;
}

s.OpenConn(sql);

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
{
    auth_items.DataSource = s.GetRead();
    auth_items.DataBind();
}
else
{
    auth_item.DataSource = s.GetRead();
    auth_item.DataBind();
}
```

The problem is that I get 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' on auth_item.DataBind().
First repeater works fine and displays the data, but the second one won't work and instead, throws me an error.
I debugged it and DataSource for the second repeater is not null, and sql returns a value.

What seems to be the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table2 doesn't have a name column?

Comment: It does. Both tables have all their columns.
I think that the error would be different then.

Comment: So it contains nulls. Exception occurs when You call ToString() method on the page.

Comment: This was the simple example.
Original one was a bit complex, so the last one was null in the database and the first one have a value and I get error on the first one, so it confuses me.
Anyhow, you are right. I left only the eval and now works.
Thank you!